# WebAPI : Get controller object from System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, controller, action-filter

I want to call some controller's method from `System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute` (pay attention, it's WebApi, not MVC).

I found `ControllerDescriptor` object, but found only way to create new controller instance, not using current:

```
var controllerDescriptor = actionContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor;

var controller = (BaseApiController)controllerDescriptor.CreateController(actionContext.Request);
var companyId = controller.GetCompanyIdFromClaims();
```

is it possible to get current instance of controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get it from the action context's controller context, which has a

```
public IHttpController Controller { get; set; }
```

property

[HttpControllerContext.Controller Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.controllers.httpcontrollercontext.controller(v=vs.118).aspx#P:System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerContext.Controller)

For example:

```
var controller = (MyControllerType)actionContext.ControllerContext.Controller;
```